# ZFS - Always Out of Memory

Tags: ram, zfs

I read that ZFS was set to use all physical memory except 1GB on systems that have 4GB or more. Since I have virtual machines running my home-server that is running the ZFS filesystem, I wanted to manually reduce this so that my VMs have allocated space, and I have some breathing room for future KVM deployments.

I understood that setting the following line in the `/etc/modprobe.d/zfs.conf` file would limit ZFS to just utilizing 4GB.

```
options zfs zfs_arc_max=4294967296
```

After a reboot, htop shows that a significant chunk of my RAM has been allocated, but there is lot's of unused space.

However, after a period of time, RAM utilization will increase until we start going into swap as shown below:

[image]
*Htop of Home Server with tasks sorted by RES usage*

### Question

Did I configure something incorrectly, or is there something else that I also need to set to reduce ZFS's footprint? Perhaps it is not ZFS but there is something else eating my RAM that I do not know about?

### Extra Info

The output of `cat /proc/spl/kstat/zfs/arcstats` is as follows:

```
5 1 0x01 85 4080 4981548270 615775159747876
name                            type data
hits                            4    46287364
misses                          4    2610021
demand_data_hits                4    30804990
demand_data_misses              4    578061
demand_metadata_hits            4    9829556
demand_metadata_misses          4    357556
prefetch_data_hits              4    2489500
prefetch_data_misses            4    1569248
prefetch_metadata_hits          4    3163318
prefetch_metadata_misses        4    105156
mru_hits                        4    12907488
mru_ghost_hits                  4    114469
mfu_hits                        4    27727068
mfu_ghost_hits                  4    464039
deleted                         4    2749215
recycle_miss                    4    8133
mutex_miss                      4    740
evict_skip                      4    62122
evict_l2_cached                 4    0
evict_l2_eligible               4    270710646272
evict_l2_ineligible             4    122732333056
hash_elements                   4    268203
hash_elements_max               4    268941
hash_collisions                 4    7490083
hash_chains                     4    71651
hash_chain_max                  4    9
p                               4    1982394368
c                               4    4294967296
c_min                           4    4194304
c_max                           4    4294967296
size                            4    4294834528
hdr_size                        4    86552992
data_size                       4    3125542912
meta_size                       4    526384640
other_size                      4    556353984
anon_size                       4    540672
anon_evict_data                 4    0
anon_evict_metadata             4    0
mru_size                        4    1985674752
mru_evict_data                  4    1692532736
mru_evict_metadata              4    124579328
mru_ghost_size                  4    2308680192
mru_ghost_evict_data            4    1841692672
mru_ghost_evict_metadata        4    466987520
mfu_size                        4    1665712128
mfu_evict_data                  4    1432485888
mfu_evict_metadata              4    56686592
mfu_ghost_size                  4    1953543680
mfu_ghost_evict_data            4    1462370304
mfu_ghost_evict_metadata        4    491173376
l2_hits                         4    0
l2_misses                       4    0
l2_feeds                        4    0
l2_rw_clash                     4    0
l2_read_bytes                   4    0
l2_write_bytes                  4    0
l2_writes_sent                  4    0
l2_writes_done                  4    0
l2_writes_error                 4    0
l2_writes_hdr_miss              4    0
l2_evict_lock_retry             4    0
l2_evict_reading                4    0
l2_free_on_write                4    0
l2_abort_lowmem                 4    0
l2_cksum_bad                    4    0
l2_io_error                     4    0
l2_size                         4    0
l2_asize                        4    0
l2_hdr_size                     4    0
l2_compress_successes           4    0
l2_compress_zeros               4    0
l2_compress_failures            4    0
memory_throttle_count           4    0
duplicate_buffers               4    0
duplicate_buffers_size          4    0
duplicate_reads                 4    0
memory_direct_count             4    2561
memory_indirect_count           4    36032
arc_no_grow                     4    0
arc_tempreserve                 4    0
arc_loaned_bytes                4    0
arc_prune                       4    0
arc_meta_used                   4    1169291616
arc_meta_limit                  4    3221225472
arc_meta_max                    4    1490740400
```

---

### Update

I have run the [ps-mem tool](http://blog.programster.org/2015/04/05/ps-mem-another-linux-memory-monitoring-tool/) to perform a breakdown of the memory being utilized by all applcations, and it comes to just 8.3 GB. That combined with the `4294834528` bytes (4GiB) that the ZFS ARC apparently has should only come to 12 GiB, but you can clearly see that I am exceeding that by roughly a further 3-4 GiB. Perhaps the ARC isn't properly releasing RAM or something?

---

### Update 5th May 2015 - Temporary Workaround

Running the following command appears to clear the memory usage as [demonstrated in this youtube video](https://youtu.be/yurVpwKkjQ4).

```
sync; echo 2 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

[More info about this command](http://www.tecmint.com/clear-ram-memory-cache-buffer-and-swap-space-on-linux/).

Comment: ZFS services need more memory "memory hungry applications" ;-)

Comment: I don't use ZFS as I think it's too greedy, but you may find this helpful: https://wiki.freebsd.org/ZFSTuningGuide and also : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116217/optimised-zfs-in-low-ram-environment-feasibility

Comment: Do you know am alternative system where I can "grow" and re-balance a RAID 10 array other than BTRFS, which I cannot use with KVM? Currently looking into ceph.

Comment: 21 June 2015 - Is it just me or has this issue been fixed in a recent kernel update?

Comment: what is your primarycache? have you have dedup enabled and what is sync value?

Answer (score 2):

ZFS also uses a lot of [SLAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation) space in the kernel. You can check how much SLAB it is using by either checking `/proc/meminfo` or by installing `nmon`.

More detailed information about slab usage can be found under `/proc/slabinfo` and `/proc/spl/kmem/slab`

It's worth reading [this](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/ZFSonLinuxMemoryWhere) to understand more about the memory usage of ZFS.